Does the cycloheptatrienyl anion avoid forming an antiaromatic compound through an sp3 hybridisation?

In the picture above you can see a cycloheptatrienyl anion.
In an exercise, our tutor marked the 1st C as sp3-hybridised without providing an explanation. From what I have understood after doing some research, this is because if it was sp2-hybridised, the molecule would form an antiaromatic compound (it's cyclic, flat, all C's are sp2-hybridised and the Hückel rule yields: 8 pi electrons --> 2n+2=8 not solvable for an even number).
This means the molecule contains adjacent p orbitals with paralel spin (--> anti binding), which makes the entire compound unstable. Hence, the compound can only persist if the 1st C is sp3 hybridised and thus does not participate in the delocalised pi electron system, the compound would not be antiaromatic anymore. Is this assumption correct?
